# CartoDB/Leaflet bring layer to front

Tags: leaflet, carto

I've got 2 layers being rendered separately with this:

```
var layerSource = {
        user_name: 'jonmrich',
        type: 'cartodb',
        sublayers: [{
            sql: "SELECT * FROM " + carto_table + " WHERE type = 'red_blank'",
            cartocss: '#location_fusion_table {marker-file: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.cartodb.users-assets.production/production/jonmrich/assets/20150203194453red_pin.png);marker-width:25;marker-allow-overlap: true;}'
        }, {
            sql: "SELECT * FROM " + carto_table + " WHERE type = 'small_blue'",
            cartocss: '#location_fusion_table {marker-fill:#1d5492;marker-width:5;marker-line-width: 0.5;marker-line-color:#fff;marker-allow-overlap: true;}'
        }]
    };
```

and later:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map_object, layerSource, options)
        .addTo(map_object)
```

Here's what ends up happening:

[image]

What I'd like to have is where the red pins ALWAYS show on top of the blue circles. If I turn overlap to `false`, I lose a lot of detail, but the blue circles aren't on top of my red pins. Is there some sort of "z-index" or "bring to front" that I can employ here?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Leaflet function setZIndex, although reordering the addition of the layers also work.

For example:

```
      cartodb.createLayer(map, {
      user_name: 'username',
      type: 'cartodb',
      sublayers: [{
         sql: baseSqlA,
         cartocss: cartocss
      }]
    })
    .addTo(map)
    .done(function(layer) {
          layer.setZIndex(1);

    });

    cartodb.createLayer(map, {
      user_name: 'username',
      type: 'cartodb',
     sublayers: [{
         sql: baseSqlB,
         cartocss:cartocss
      }]
    })
    .addTo(map)
    .done(function(layer) {
      layer.setZIndex(0);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this myself...

I just swapped the order in which I'm rendering the sublayers. The second one always ends up on top.

[image]

It also seems that both layers need `marker-allow-overlap: true;`